# How to prove that $(A \cup B) \oplus (B \cup C) = (A \oplus C) - B$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> Prove
>
> $(A \cup B) \oplus (B \cup C) = (A \oplus C) - B$

It's a problem I met when studying discrete mathematics. I'm a starter so I'm still unfamiliar with some operations.
Here is how I tried and failed:

$$\begin{align}
&(A \cup B - B \cup C)\cup(B \cup C - A \cup B) \\
&=B\cup(A-C)\cup B \cup(C-A)\\
&=B\cup(A-C)\cup(C-A)\\
&=B\cup(A \oplus C)\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: To prove that an arbitrary element $x$ is in the left side of your equation if and only if it's in the right side, consider separately the case that $x\in B$ and the case that $x\notin B$. Each case turns out to be quite easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We want $(A \cup B) \oplus (B \cup C) = (A \oplus C) - B$

case 1: If $x \in B$, then $x \in (A \cup B) \oplus (B \cup C)$ cannot hold, as $x$ is in *both* $A \cup$ *and* $B \cup C$. Also $x \notin (A \oplus C) - B$ by definition.

So the only interesting case is when $x \notin B$. Then $x$ is in the left hand side iff $x \in A \oplus C$ because e.g. $x \in B \cup C$ implies $x \in C$ in this case and ditto for $A \cup B$ and $A$.
And so it's clearly in the right hand side and vice versa too. QED.